# Reactive component / update component ( modal ) Vue Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm beginner and i need help,
It does not update without closing the modal.
To simplify, at the click of my button, it should display the result of my data.
And if I change the button without closing the modal, I would like the result (multiplication of text1 and text2) to be updated.

thanks in advance

https://codesandbox.io/s/red-leftpad-6oed4?file=/src/timeline.vue

Comment: Welcome. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to show code in your question (not just at an external site), and please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question rather than list a bunch of tags.

Answer (score 0):

In `modal.vue` of your codesandbox, uses one `watch` or `computed property` to get latest `infosModal` (watch will be triggered or computed property will be re-calc when the dependencies are changed). And `timeline.vue` should do same thing.

For example, in `modal.vue`, adds below:

```
  watch: {
    'infosModal': function (newVal) {
      this.test = newVal
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedInfosModal: function() {
      return Object.assign({}, this.infosModal);
    }
  },
```

[Updated CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-wind-bnrz7)

Comment: Thanks ! it's perfect